# Android 2.3.3 touch by explore

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am developing app for blind community. I want to give an option for the user to explore the screen by scraping finger through the screen (exploring by touch). I am unable to find any api to build this functionality. I am trying to achieve this in android 2.3.3 (api level 10).

I know in Android 4.1 talkback with 'touch by explore' functionality comes by default, but I want to give this feature to the users who are using below android 4.1 devices.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want try using the [AccessibilityShim](http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/source/browse/trunk/libraries/widgets/access-shim/src/com/googlecode/eyesfree/widget/AccessibilityShim.java) library from Eyes-Free Project. It implements ICS-style touch exploration for individual Activities in Gingerbread and below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // This call must occur after setContentView().
    AccessiblityShim.attachToActivity(this);
}
```

It can also be applied to Dialogs.

```
AccessiblityShim.attachToDialog(dialog);
```