# What is the option in Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread LIKE THE ACCESSIBILITY OPTION ("Explore by touch") in Android 4.0.4 ICECREAMSANDWICH

Tags: android

I want to use Google's TALKBACK app for accessibility, in order to make it accessible by a blind person.
        i tried using it on my android OS 4.0.4 IcecreamSandwich and 2.3.3 Gingerbread.

```
   Settings for 4.0 Icecreamsandwich are as follow:
         settings --> accessibility --> talkback - ON --> back --> Explore by touch - ON

   And Settings for 2.3.3 Gingerbread are as follow:
         settings --> accessibility - check --> talkback - check

  There is no option for "Explore by touch" in android 2.3.3 gingerbread.
   What is the alternative for "explore by touch" option in Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread ?
```

I have asked same question on Google group https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/bqsP6Hbs5kE

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow (and the android-developers Google Group) is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent for Explore By Touch in Gingerbread. It was introduced with Ice Cream Sandwich.

Prior to ICS, Talkback can only speak views which are focusable.

Further information can be found at http://www.apps4android.org/?p=3628 and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html.

The answer to [Android 2.3.3 touch by explore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296612/android-2-3-3-touch-by-explore/14988769#14988769) suggests that the [AccessibilityShim](http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/source/browse/trunk/libraries/widgets/access-shim/src/com/googlecode/eyesfree/widget/AccessibilityShim.java) library from the Eyes-Free Project can be used to implement explore by touch functionality in your app.